# Hot to force JS code to have annotations for functions, classes, their methods and fat arrow methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I would like my eslint to check that there is a jsdoc defined for functions, classes, their methods and fat arrow methods.

I've spent last few days playing (and even trying to fork and rewrite something) with different settings and plugins for eslint. (eslint-plugin-jsdoc for example). There are some options to do half of what I need. And fat arrow functions give the biggest pain because they are not standard and not supported by pure eslint, you need to use babel for them, and there is no such thing implemented here https://github.com/babel/eslint-plugin-babel/issues/136

What am I doing wrong here? (I would like not to believe that there is no way to do such a thing and nobody has implemented this in a whole JS community).

May be it is possible to do that in TypeScript linter? But given that I don't want to have TS in my project - can I at the same time disable everything except these rules?

**Update**: added a screenshot. I expect to have a linting error at the line 15 as well.

[image]

Comment: You can always write your own lint rules. It's a bit intimidating at the start, but it can be of great use. I mean, I for one would use a plugin that allows this.

Comment: Arrow functions **is** standard js. And eslint's default parser supports it with the config `{"parserOptions": {"ecmaVersion": 6}}`.

Comment: There is no such thing as "arrow methods". Are you talking of arrow functions being used as property values with the class fields proposal?

Comment: @Bergi yes, exactly

Answer (score 2):

Your use cases are covered by the built-in rule [requre-jsdoc](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-jsdoc).

Eslint is shipped with es6+ support, if you set `ecmaVersion: 6` in the config.

```
module.exports = {
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
  },

  rules: {
    "require-jsdoc": [
      2,
      {
        require: {
          FunctionDeclaration: true,
          MethodDefinition: true,
          ClassDeclaration: true,
          ArrowFunctionExpression: true,
          FunctionExpression: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Great, thanks! One thing is left - AFAIK eslint without babel does not support arrow methods (not sure how exactly this is called). See the screenshot I've added to the question - no error at line 15 where I would expect it.

Comment: It is called class fields declarations.  See https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields .

Comment: @ok, thank you, but is it possible to check if they have annotations?